# Create child actors based on the request pattern

Tags: scala, websocket, playframework, akka

I am trying to create a web socket server using Play Framework where response from server should be synchronous or asynchronous based on request.

The request will be processed in Parent actor .Based on the action in the request, child actor will be created and message will be passed to child actor for processing and response will be sent back to the controller.

There are predefined actions and sample request for some actions are as follows,
[,,]

["1234","Boot","{"system":"ABCD"}"]

["5678","Start","{"system":"EFGH", "currenTime":"1559548762638"}"]

```
@Singleton
class RequestController @Inject()(cc: ControllerComponents)(implicit system: ActorSystem, mat: Materializer) extends AbstractController(cc) {
    def ws = WebSocket.accept[String, String] {req =>
    ActorFlow.actorRef { out =>
      ParentActor.props(out)
    }
  }
}

object ParentActor {
  def props(out: ActorRef) = Props(new ParentActor(out))
}

class ParentActor(out : ActorRef) extends Actor {
    override def receive: Receive = {
         case msg: String => 
         //String split opeartion to find the action.
         //create child actor for the action and pass the message to the child actor
            val action = msg.split(",")[2]
            if("Boot".equals(action)){
                val bootActor: ActorRef = actorSystem.actorOf(Props[BootActor])
                childActor ! msg
            }else if("Start".equals(action)){
                val startActor: ActorRef = actorSystem.actorOf(Props[StartActor])
                startActor ! msg
            }
         case msg: Response => out ! msg
    }
}

case class Response(name:String, msg:String)

class BootActor extends Actor{
    override def receive: Receive = {
        case msg : String => 
        sender() ! Response("ABC",msg) 
    }
}

class StartActor extends Actor{
    override def receive: Receive = {
        case msg : String => 
        sender() ! Response("Efgh",msg) 
    }
}
```

Right now i am getting the action from the request and create a child actor for the action and pass the message to the child actor for processing.
But i am not sure is there any better way or design pattern to process the request and create a child actor instead of String operation?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there appears to be a typo in your code:

```
if ("Boot".equals(action)) {
  val bootActor: ActorRef = actorSystem.actorOf(Props[BootActor])
  childActor ! msg
} else if ("Start".equals(action)) {
  val startActor: ActorRef = actorSystem.actorOf(Props[StartActor])
  startActor ! msg
}
```

The message in the first conditional clause should be sent to `bootActor` instead of `childActor`, which is undefined in your code snippet.

Another issue is that you're using `actorSystem.actorOf` to create the child actors. This method creates "top-level" actors, which should be kept to a minimum. Actors created with `actorSystem.actorOf` are under the supervision of the [guardian actor](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5.23/general/supervision.html#user-the-guardian-actor). What this means in relation to your code is that when `ParentActor` is stopped (i.e., when a WebSocket is closed, Play stops the actor used in `ActorFlow`, as documented [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/ScalaWebSockets#Detecting-when-a-WebSocket-has-closed)), the multiple instances of `BootActor` and `StartActor` will *not* be stopped, leaving you with a bunch of idle top-level actors. The remedy is to use `context.actorOf` to create instances of `BootActor` and `StartActor`: doing so makes these instances children of `ParentActor`.

Also, you should use the `==` operator instead of the `equals` method.

Here are the aforementioned changes:

```
if ("Boot" == action) {
  val bootActor: ActorRef = context.actorOf(Props[BootActor])
  bootActor ! msg
} else if ("Start" == action) {
  val startActor: ActorRef = context.actorOf(Props[StartActor])
  startActor ! msg
}
```

The above could be slightly simplified to the following:

```
val childActor =
  if (action == "Boot") context.actorOf(Props[BootActor])
  else context.actorOf(Props[StartActor])

childActor ! msg
```

To further simplify your code, don't create child actors, which in this case aren't necessary. Move all the logic of interacting with the `out` actor into a single actor.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @Jeffrey Chung. By the way the above implementation is not blocking rite and good to take loads of request ?